# Providing remote worker directories on Gearman Manager

Tags: job-scheduling, gearman, php-5.4

I am using [GearmanManager](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager) to control my workers on [gearman](http://gearman.org/). I have got it working with workers on the same machine as gearman manager. However I would like to connect to workers on remote hosts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to install GearmanManager on every instance where the workers are running. You can then control the workers on that instrance. The workers can connect to remote Gearman Job server.